# I am not able to solve this question on set theory I tried but I am unsure of my answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers such that each element $n$ in $S$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. The sum of the digits of $n$ is a prime number.
2. The sum of the digits of $n^2$ is a perfect square.

Prove or disprove the existence of an infinite subset $T$ of $S$ such that for every $n$ in $T$, the sum of the digits of $n^3$ is a perfect cube.

**Attempt**

To prove the existence of an infinite subset $T$ of $S$ such that for every $n$ in $T$, the sum of the digits of $n^3$ is a perfect cube, we need to show that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ satisfying the given conditions.

I analyzed the conditions provided:

1. The sum of the digits of $n$ is a prime number.
2. The sum of the digits of $n^2$ is a perfect square.

I tried to construct such an infinite subset $T$ by considering the properties of the conditions.

First, i started with the condition that the sum of the digits of $n$ is a prime number. This condition restricts the possible values of $n$ to those whose digit sums are primes. Since there are infinitely many prime numbers, there are infinitely many such $n$.

Second, i considered the condition that the sum of the digits of $n^2$ is a perfect square. For any given prime digit sum $p$, there are infinitely many numbers whose digit sum is $p$. Let's denote one such number as $n_1$. Now, if $n_1$ satisfies the condition that the sum of the digits of $n_1^2$ is a perfect square, we can include it in our subset $T$.

Now if I continue this process to construct infinitely many numbers in $T$, each satisfying the given conditions. Since there are infinitely many prime numbers and infinitely many numbers for each prime digit sum, we can conclude that there exists an infinite subset$T$ of $S$ satisfying the condition that the sum of the digits of $n^3$ is a perfect cube for every $n$ in $T$.

Therefore, can we say that the existence of such infinite subset $T$ is proven?

**I am unsure of my answer. Is this correct?**

Comment: Note:  I don't understand your argument.  You appear to simply assert that you can find natural numbers with some desired properties, but this isn't obvious.

Comment: The set $T = \{2 \times 10^n\}$ indeed gets the job done, as $2$ is a prime, $4$ is a perfect square, and $8$ is a perfect cube.

Comment: @DS  Not sure what I was thinking there.  Thanks!  Of course $\{2\times 10^n\}$ works, as you point out.

Comment: To the OP: Your attempt is flawed. If $A$ is infinite, $B$ is infinite, then $A \cap B$ is not necessarily infinite.

Comment: @DS It's easier than that because $11$ works as well. In fact, I believe you can construct numbers with two ones separated by zeroes so that the square has non-zero digits $1,2,1$ and the digits of the cube are $1,3,3,1$. That would give the infinite set.

Comment: @JohnDouma of course, there may be other solutions too

Comment: Now you have proven that $A = \{$digits of $n$ add to prim$\}$ is inifinite and that $B=\{$digits of $n^2$ is a square$\}$ is infinite but not that $A\cap B$ is infinite.  Consider this argumeent there are infinitely many even numbers and there are infinitely many primes so therefore there are infinitely many even primes.

Comment: "For any given prime digit sum p, there are infinitely many numbers whose digit sum is p"Actually you haven't proven that at all.  You proved that there are infinite number of integers add to a prime number, you haven't proven that for a given prime there are an infinite ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers of the form $10^n+1$ work for all positive $n$.

The digits of $10^n+1$ sum to $2$.

$(10^n+1)^2=10^{2n}+2\times 10^n+1$ so the digits sum to $4$.

$(10^n+1)^3=10^{3n}+3\times 10^{2n}+3\times 10^n+1$ and the digits sum to $8$.

Comment: Also, $(10^n+1)10^k$ work too.

Comment: I still don't get the point you were trying to make in the comments. Doesn't the set $\{2,20,200,2000\ldots \}$ work too?

Comment: @DS Yes, it does which shows that there are more than one.

Comment: No, $p=5$doesn't work, neither does p = 7.